# Fail to create a controller file with make command in Symfony

Tags: symfony

I'm learning Symfony now and I ran into a problem trying to create a controller file with the make command. The path of the project is "E:\web_dev\testproject". When I ran the command

```
php bin/console make:controller
```

and then entered the name of the controller, it returns an error "Failed to create "E:\web_dev\testproject//E:\web_dev\testproject\vendor\composer/../../src/Controller"". What is the problem?

Comment: What version of Symfony are you working with?

Comment: I get it from composer, I think it's 4.02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem.
I have found this [Thread](https://openclassrooms.com/forum/sujet/probleme-de-generation-dentity-sur-symfony-4) and it seems that the problem is in the Maker Bundle. After running "composer remove maker" and "composer require maker 1.0.2" it works by me.

In the other Thread they used Maker Version 1.0.0 but in Symfony4 the generated AbstactController do not Functionaly so I use Version 1.0.2.

Hope it help you.

Comment: Thanks it works. There're some random cmd crashes after a command was executed but that's probably another issue.

Comment: The maker bundle got a new update to version 1.1.1. Newly generated controllers are now working again. A controller and a template are created.